# registerNib fails for custom UICollectionViewCell in my UICollectionViewController

Tags: xib, uicollectionviewcell

I see a lot of problems out there related to the same error but none of the solutions worked for me. I don't see what is wrong and I keep getting the following exception:

```
-[UICollectionView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm sure it's a silly thing. Happy to hear your thoughts!

[Here is my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFofg.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Silly, indeed. I was using

```
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier
```

instead of

```
registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier
```